# Android Linkify A Completely Unrelated String

Tags: android, linkify

I want to do something like 
 `Click <a href='www.google.com'>Here</a>`

in android. I tried using the following:

```
TextView sponsoredlink = new TextView(this);
                sponsoredlink.setId(R.id.details_sponsored_link);
                sponsoredlink.setText("Click Here");

                Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("Here");

                String link = "www.google.com";

                Linkify.addLinks(sponsoredlink, pattern, link);
```

but i just end up with a link to www.google.comhere [sic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, I found a tutorial on transform filters and adapted it to my own ends:

```
TextView sponsoredlink = new TextView(this);
                sponsoredlink.setId(R.id.details_sponsoredlink);
                sponsoredlink.setText("Click Here");

                TransformFilter mentionFilter = new TransformFilter() {
                    public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
                        return new String("http://www.google.com");
                    }
                };

                // Match @mentions and capture just the username portion of the text.
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".");
                String scheme = "";
                Linkify.addLinks(sponsoredlink, pattern, scheme, null, mentionFilter);
```

I decided I wanted to turn the whole text into one big link in the end, so I did a pattern that matched the whole text.

Then I created a transform filter which just ignores whatever you give it and returns the URL I wanted to take people to

The scheme also has to be the empty string so nothing gets added on the end

Finally I used linkify to put it all together