# get Url in TextView and play it on WebView in android

Tags: android

I want to get url in TextView `android:text="My web site: http://hurriyettv.cubecdn.net/2013/03/12/Viplay_14560_240p.mp4"` and I try to play this url on WebView in android.I tryed like below code but it doesn't work. How can I get Url and play it. I try to do run video in device not browser.

```
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        vw = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
        URLSpan[] urlSpans = txtView.getUrls();
        for (URLSpan span : urlSpans) {
            vw.loadUrl(span.getURL());
        }
```

TextView in Layout

```
<TextView
    android:text="My web site: http://hurriyettv.cubecdn.net/2013/03/12/Viplay_14560_240p.mp4"
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

     android:autoLink="web"
    >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it worked to me.

```
txtView =(TextView)viewflipper.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
txtView .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    String url = "http://" +txtView .getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
   }
});
```

EDIT*

```
    final txtView myClickableUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
  myClickableUrl.setText("My web site: http://hurriyettv.cubecdn.net/2013/03/12/Viplay_14560_240p.mp4");
  Linkify.addLinks(myClickableUrl, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: You can try to create another TextView witch text is "My web site is: " and then create another TextView with the url, and i think it will work.

Comment: it works, but I need to get it as String to play in WebView,how to convert Linkify.addLinks(txtView, Linkify.WEB_URLS); to String

Comment: Try to implement your code on this example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249013/android-linkify-a-completely-unrelated-string?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

getUrls() won't return anything unless the links have been set up. Add this code to your onCreate() function, or wherever you set up the viewflipper:

```
txtView = (TextView)viewflipper.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
Linkify.addLinks(txtView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: it works, but I need to get it as String to play in WebView,how to convert Linkify.addLinks(txtView, Linkify.WEB_URLS); to String

Comment: Your code is already doing that. span.getURL() returns a String